# How to distinct json array by email using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to distinct JSON array by value, using javascript. Below is my JSON array. I want to calculate the size of distinct elements.

```
 [
       {
                "_id": "5aaa4f8cd0ccf521304dc6bd",
                "email": "abc@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5aaa50a0ac40d32404c8bab7",
                "email": "pqr@gmail.com",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5aa8ace3323eeb001414a2c5",
                "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5aa86645323eeb001414a2af",
                "email": "abc@gmail.com"

            }
    ]
```

The expected results should be 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a JavaScript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: You can use something like this `Array.from(new Set(arr.map(({email}) => email)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce`.

This alternative stores the previous emails to increment the count.

```js
var array = [{    "_id": "5aaa4f8cd0ccf521304dc6bd",    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"  },  {    "_id": "5aaa50a0ac40d32404c8bab7",    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com",  },  {    "_id": "5aa8ace3323eeb001414a2c5",    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"  },  {    "_id": "5aa86645323eeb001414a2af",    "email": "bspilak@cooperequipment.ca"  },  {    "_id": "5aa92c7d66c8820014813ed8",    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"  }];

var count = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (!a[c.email]) a[c.email] = ++a.count;
  return a;
}, {count: 0}).count;

console.log(count);
```

Using the object `Set`

- Map to arrays of emails.
- Initialize the object Set with that mapped array.
- Get the `count` using the property `size`.

```js
var array = [{    "_id": "5aaa4f8cd0ccf521304dc6bd",    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com"  },  {    "_id": "5aaa50a0ac40d32404c8bab7",    "email": "srjahir32@gmail.com",  },  {    "_id": "5aa8ace3323eeb001414a2c5",    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"  },  {    "_id": "5aa86645323eeb001414a2af",    "email": "bspilak@cooperequipment.ca"  },  {    "_id": "5aa92c7d66c8820014813ed8",    "email": "g.anshul@gmail.com"  }],
    mapped = array.map(e => e.email),
    set = new Set(mapped),
    count = set.size;

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupBy method of lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy and then get the length of the result array